# dbup dotnet core support issue

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, dbup

i tried to get dbup from nuget for my asp.net core 1.1 project

`Install-Package dbup-mysql -Version 3.3.5`

and end up with this issue.

> Install-Package : Package dbup-mysql 3.3.5 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package dbup-mysql 3.3.5
>   supports: net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5) At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package dbup-mysql -Version 3.3.5
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Install-Package : Package dbup 3.3.5 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package dbup 3.3.5 supports:
>   net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5) At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package dbup-mysql -Version 3.3.5
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes
>   for 'Portal'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package dbup-mysql -Version 3.3.5
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

is dbup not support dotnet core yet?

Comment: According to the [issue](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/issues/174) you've commented on, it should work with ASP.NET Core 2.0 due to the .NET Standard 2.0 shimming. It's not going to work with 1.x.